# SELECT monthly record form database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, datetime

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM con_transactions;
+------+------+---------------------+--------+
| t_id | p_id | date                | amount |
+------+------+---------------------+--------+
|   10 |    1 | 2016-02-17 19:24:05 | 1800   |
|   12 |    2 | 2016-02-18 11:40:13 | 200    |
|   17 |    3 | 2016-02-18 11:42:04 | 100    |
|   19 |    4 | 2016-02-18 11:45:43 | 1      |
|   20 |    5 | 2016-02-18 11:45:54 | 999    |
|   21 |    1 | 2016-02-18 11:46:02 | 1500   |
|   41 |    2 | 2016-02-18 17:23:14 | 500    |
|   42 |    3 | 2016-02-18 17:23:14 | 500    |
|   43 |    4 | 2016-02-18 17:23:15 | 500    |
|   44 |    5 | 2016-02-18 17:23:16 | 500    |
|   45 |    1 | 2016-02-18 17:23:16 | 500    |
|   46 |    2 | 2016-02-18 17:23:16 | 500    |
|   47 |    3 | 2016-02-18 17:23:17 | 500    |
|   48 |    4 | 2016-02-18 17:23:17 | 500    |
|   49 |    5 | 2016-02-18 17:23:18 | 500    |
|   50 |    1 | 2016-02-18 17:25:54 | 1000   |
|   51 |    1 | 2016-02-18 17:26:22 | 3000   |
|   52 |    2 | 2016-02-18 17:48:59 | 10     |
|   53 |    1 | 2016-02-18 17:48:59 | 10     |
|   55 |    1 | 2016-02-19 10:20:12 | 1000   |
+------+------+---------------------+--------+
```

HOW Can I Select current month or last month All Transactions record. All Month are not 30 days. So How can I Select January or other month record with SELECT query. I Try this query

```
SELECT * FROM con_transactions WHERE date > '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND date < '2016-02-01 00:00:00';
```

This is not so smart .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `month()` and `year()` to directly find any given month of a year.

```
SELECT * FROM con_transactions WHERE year(date)  = 2016 AND month(date) = 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

One method is to use formats such as as YYYYMM for the date comparison:

```
SELECT *
FROM con_transactions
WHERE YEAR(date) * 100 + MONTH(date) = YEAR(CURDATE())*100 + MONTH(CURDATE());
```

However, that has the drawback that MySQL cannot use an index for the `WHERE` clause.  So, another method is a variant of your method but using the first day of the month:

```
WHERE date >= str_to_date(concat_ws('-', year(curdate()), month(curdate()), '01'), '%Y-%m-%d) and
      date < str_to_date(concat_ws('-', year(dateadd(curdate(), interval 1 month)), month(dateadd(curdate(), interval 1 month), '01'), '%Y-%m-%d)
```